# Install tomcat 7 on windows server 2008 using puppet ( master is ubuntu )

Tags: windows, java-7, puppet

Has anyone installed tomcat and jdk7 packages on windows server 2008 using puppet.

puppet master is (Ubuntu)
puppet agent is (windows server 2008)

```
node 'puppetwindows' {
package {'jdk7 v7.0.79.1':
           ensure => present,
           source => 'puppet:///modules/jdk//jdk-7u79-windows-x64.exe',
           path => “C:\jdk-7u79-windows-x64.exe”
           install_options => ['/VERYSILENT'],
```

below is the output;

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could
 not parse for environment production: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII at /etc
/puppet/manifests/site.pp:1 on node puppetwindows.pramati.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Comment: There might be invisible characters or similar on line 1 of your `site.pp`. Check it carefully. If in doubt, remove that line and retype it from scratch.

Comment: @FelixFrank likely UTF8 with BOM. See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your file is using UTF-8 with BOM. Convert it to UTF-8 w/out BOM.

You should also use `puppet parser validate path\to\manifest.pp` so you can get an idea of whether the file contains good Puppet code and as a byproduct whether Puppet can read the file (are the encodings usable?).

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted the puppet master and it worked fine.

installed chocolatey(package manager for windows same as apt-get on Ubuntu) on both Ubuntu(puppet master) windows(puppet agent)

and with the below code I was able to install tomcat successfully.

```
node 'puppetwindows.XXXX.com' {
        package { 'tomcat':
                provider => 'chocolatey',
                ensure => 'latest',
                }
}
```